# Android bar chart: undo selection

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

There's some way to undo a selection on Mikephil charting? I have an application which opens an activity when I selects one value in a bar chart. That works fine, however, when I returns to activity that contains the chart, the selection remains. So, when I selects again, the selection is cleared and the activity does not open. What I want is ever I select a value on bar chart the function "onValueSelected" be executed. How can I do that?

That is the code fragment which calls assyncronously an activity when a value is selected.

```
      mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
                if(e.getVal() == 0);
                else {
                    GetClientesCadastradosDiaAsync task = new GetClientesCadastradosDiaAsync();
                    task.execute();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected() {
                // do nothing
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your `onValueSelected()` method, call:

```
chart.highlightValues(null);
```

Now, this will only remove the highlighting. If you select that same bar again, `onNothingSelected()` will be called.

Therefore, in `onNothingSelected()`, again call `onValueSelected()`. You will have to pass the parameters here, but looks like you will only need the `Entry` parameter, and for the other 2 you can pass `null`.